# Using Clients.Others with SignalR - ASP.net/VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, signalr

Here I have a simple hub class:

```
Public Class MessageHub
    Inherits Hub
    Public Sub sendAlert(Message As String, Title As String, Type As String)
        Clients.Others.sendAlert(Message, Title, Type)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Declaring it as a public sub is the only way that I can access the Clients.Others property. However, doing it like this will not let me call `MessageHub.sendAlert()` without an object reference; I tried creating an object reference, but ran into a runtime error saying SignalR doesn't support creating your own references like that.

There's not much documentation around with SignalR v2 and VB.net, and the pages I can find mention nothing about how to use Client.Others.

What's the best way to go about this situation?

Comment: I'm aware of using a context if I wanted to use clients.All, but using clients.others requires being called inside a hub class method itself, which is the issue.

Comment: In that case, this is a continuation of [Ignoring a client when broadcasting a message with SignalR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104344/ignoring-a-client-when-broadcasting-a-message-with-signalr). Also see [SignalR - HubContext and Hub.Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149949/signalr-hubcontext-and-hub-context) where David Fowler (MSFT programmer) says there is no caller outside the hub, suggesting that what you're attempting doesn't logical make sense (how can there be others if there's no caller?)